# In animation nodes rotation around an object

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I'm trying to find how to make rotating an objet around an other object using animation nodes.
It seem something basic to me but there is not so much solution in google for this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Combine Matrices`](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/matrix/combine_matrices.html) node. You can add more to the matrix list for more complex transformations.

[image]

Comment: It works ! thank you !